# C++ Plist Parser

Tags: c++, ubuntu, plist

Which is the best opensource Plist Parser in C++ that can be installed from the ubuntu repo?

I have read about libplist++. But I couldnt find any documentation regarding its usage.
Can anyone suggest a good plist parser in C++ that has documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu packages unfortunately have only  libplist++. I don't know why you strongly need a package from ubuntu repo. Can't you use GitHub? In my project I used this plist serialization library: https://github.com/animetrics/PlistCpp.
It has very good examples for getting started.

Comment: since it will be implemented in multiple points/servers, getting an ubuntu repo package is better for scalability reasons.